# Unlock all disabled fields in the Magento 2 backoffice in local environment

Tags: magento, magento2

We adopt the pipeline deployment to upload the code to production.
Then all the settings are dumped in the config.php file.

As a result, the backoffice fields are disabled in the backoffice.

But we want all the fields to be editable in the local environment and after modifying, dump the configuration changes in the config.php file again.

Is there any way to get it without modifying the config.php file manually?

For more information of the pipeline deployment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/deployment/pipeline/technical-details.html

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

Basically everything that is set in config.php is part of the project itself and cannot be changed.

If you need to vary those options during the normal procedure of the ecommerce usage you can considerate the config.xml in your custom modules or some patch/upgrade scripts.